# ThrowException through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

This is not a common scenario. I am trying to invoke an exception through reflection. I have something like:
testMethod is of type MethodBuilder

```
testMethod.GetILGenerator().ThrowException(typeof(CustomException));
```

My CustomException does not have a default constructor, so the above statement errors out giving an ArgumentException. If there is a default constructor, this works fine.

So is there a way, this can work with no default constructor? Been trying for 2 hours now. :(

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.throwexception%28v=VS.95%29.aspx):

```
// This example uses the ThrowException method, which uses the default 
// constructor of the specified exception type to create the exception. If you
// want to specify your own message, you must use a different constructor; 
// replace the ThrowException method call with code like that shown below,
// which creates the exception and throws it.
//
// Load the message, which is the argument for the constructor, onto the 
// execution stack. Execute Newobj, with the OverflowException constructor
// that takes a string. This pops the message off the stack, and pushes the
// new exception onto the stack. The Throw instruction pops the exception off
// the stack and throws it.
//adderIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "DoAdd does not accept values over 100.");
//adderIL.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, _
//             overflowType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(String) }));
//adderIL.Emit(OpCodes.Throw);
```

Answer (score 5):

The `ThrowException` method essentially boils down to the following

```
Emit(OpCodes.NewObj, ...);
Emit(OpCodes.Throw);
```

The key here is to replace the first `Emit` calls with the set of IL instructions needed to create an instance of your custom exception.  Then add the `Emit(OpCodes.Throw)`

For example

```
class MyException : Exception {
  public MyException(int p1) {}
}

var ctor = typeof(MyException).GetConstructor(new Type[] {typeof(int)});
var gen = builder.GetILGenerator();
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 42);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.NewObj, ctor);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Throw);
```